# Selectively disabling axis labels in tikz-figures without modifying original file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In a current project I have the following figure structure (using example figures here):
[image]

The file has been created using two files, `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.dat}
    x y
    0 0
    1 1
    2 2
    3 3
    4 4
    5 5
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz-cache/]
\tikzset{external/force remake}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        label style={font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
        tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize}
    },
    y axis/.append style={align=center}}
\tikzset{Line Label/.style={font=\footnotesize,scale=2}}
\newcommand{\figurefontsize}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \hspace*{\fill}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub.tikz}
        \caption{Image I}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subII.tikz}
        \caption{Image II}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subIII.tikz}
        \caption{Image III}
    \end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and `sub[, II, III].tex`:

```
\pgfplotstableread{file1.dat}{\tablea}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=0, ymax=30,
        xmin=0, xmax=5,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$-entry, typically long},
        grid=major,
        legend entries={\(y_1\),\(y_2\),\(y_1+y_2\)},
        legend pos = north west
        ]
        % Select appropriate columns
        \addplot [blue, mark=*] table [x=x,y=y] {\tablea};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

`sub.tikz`, `subII.tikz` and `subIII.tikz` are identical.

As they all share the same y axis, I wanted to remove the y-axis labels from figure b) and figure c) and increase all figures in size to decrease the space between them, to use the y-axis of figure a) as common y-axis. Still, I do not want to entirely remove the white space between the figures, I still want a bit distance between the figures left.

Because I am re-using the figures at different places, though, I do not want to modify the figure files (i.e. the tikz-files) itself, but rather enable/disable the different settings from the main file.

As initial test to disable the y-labels selectively I rewrote the figure-environment into:

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \hspace*{\fill}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub.tikz}
        \caption{Image I}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/ylabel=\empty}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subII.tikz}
        \caption{Image II}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subIII.tikz}
        \caption{Image III}
    \end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}%
\end{figure}
```

to disable the y-labels for figure b) and c), but this setting did not show any results.

What would be a better way to achieve my goal, to make the figures more compact, as described above, without modifying the original tikz-files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/ylabel=\empty}` at this place won't have any effect because it will be overridden by the option `ylabel={$y$-entry, typically long}` that is added to the `axis` macro in your .tikz files.

However, your approach does work, if you use some other options that are not set insinde the .tikz files, for example `\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/ylabel style={opacity=0}}`. You can also crop the left axis using `trim axis left`.

If you crop away the left axis, the three images don't have the same width anymore, so you should probably replace `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]` by someting like `\includegraphics[height=4cm]`. Also, you need to adjust the width of each of the three `subfigures` of course.

Taken together all this, you would get the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.dat}
    x y
    0 0
    1 1
    2 2
    3 3
    4 4
    5 5
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz-cache/]
%\tikzset{external/force remake}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        label style={font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
        tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize}
    },
    y axis/.append style={align=center}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.35\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[height=4cm]{sub.tikz}
        \caption{Image I}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \pgfplotsset{trim axis left, /pgfplots/ylabel style={opacity=0}}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.275\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[height=4cm]{subII.tikz}
        \caption{Image II}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.275\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[height=4cm]{subIII.tikz}
        \caption{Image III}
    \end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I commented out the externalization stuff. But it should not make a difference.

[image]