# Replicate sidesubfloat with subcaption-package

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subcaption, subfig

Following the answer I received in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652074/61517 I wanted to make the figures even more compact by moving the corresponding labels above/to the left of the figure (as for example demonstrated by [Subfigures. To add A and B to subfigures (in the top left corner), and to label them for referencing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/310081/61517)). With the code, given as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.dat}
    x y
    0 0
    1 1
    2 2
    3 3
    4 4
    5 5
\end{filecontents*}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz-cache/]
\tikzset{external/force remake}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        label style={font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
        tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize}
    },
    y axis/.append style={align=center}}
\tikzset{Line Label/.style={font=\footnotesize,scale=2}}
\newcommand{\figurefontsize}{\footnotesize}

\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \hspace*{\fill}%
    \pgfplotsset{trim axis left, /pgfplots/ylabel style={opacity=0}}%
    \pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/xlabel style = {opacity=0}}%
    \pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/ylabel style={opacity=100}}%
    \sidesubfloat[]{\hspace{-.5cm}\includegraphics[height=.33\linewidth]{sub.tikz}\hspace{.5cm}}\hfill%
    \pgfplotsset{trim axis left, /pgfplots/ylabel style={opacity=0}}%
    \sidesubfloat[]{\hspace{-.5cm}\includegraphics[height=.33\linewidth]{subII.tikz}\hspace{.5cm}}\hfill%
    \sidesubfloat[]{\hspace{-.5cm}\includegraphics[height=.33\linewidth]{subIII.tikz}\hspace{.5cm}}\hspace*{\fill}\vspace{-.5cm}\\%

    \hspace*{\fill}%
    \pgfplotsset{trim axis left, /pgfplots/ylabel style={opacity=0}}%
    \pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/xlabel style = {opacity=100}}%
    \pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/ylabel style={opacity=100}}%
    \sidesubfloat[]{\hspace{-.5cm}\includegraphics[height=.33\linewidth]{subIV.tikz}\hspace{.5cm}}\hfill%
    \pgfplotsset{trim axis left, /pgfplots/ylabel style={opacity=0}}%
    \sidesubfloat[]{\hspace{-.5cm}\includegraphics[height=.33\linewidth]{subV.tikz}\hspace{.5cm}}\hfill%
    \sidesubfloat[]{\hspace{-.5cm}\includegraphics[height=.33\linewidth]{subVI.tikz}\hspace{.5cm}}\hspace*{\fill}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

in the main file, and

```
\pgfplotstableread{file1.dat}{\tablea}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=0, ymax=30,
        xmin=0, xmax=5,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$-entry, typically long},
        grid=major,
        legend entries={\(y_1\),\(y_2\),\(y_1+y_2\)},
        legend pos = north west
        ]
        % Select appropriate columns
        \addplot [blue, mark=*] table [x=x,y=y] {\tablea};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

in the tikz-files I got the following result:
[image]

Unfortunately, I am already heavily relying on `subcaption` in my project, and I do not want to change all other figures now, which prevents me using `subfig`. Therefore, I arrived at two problems:

- How can I replicate the demonstrated behavior by using `subfigure` (or similar, contained in `subcaption`?
- Ideally, how can I move the labels into the figures, to the top left corner, without having to place them there manually?

I am currently not sure how to solve either of them. Which options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably rename the external .tikz files to `sub1.tikz` to `sub6.tikz`, since then you can easily loop over these files which would reduce you code.

As for the caption inside the subplots, you could use an `extra x tick` that is positioned at zero opposite to the regular x ticks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
%\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz-cache/]
%\tikzset{external/force remake}

\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={
        label style={font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
        tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize}
    },
    trim axis left,
    y axis/.append style={align=center},
    extra x ticks={0},
    extra x tick style={ticklabel pos=top}
    }

\begin{filecontents*}{file1.dat}
    x y
    0 0
    1 1
    2 2
    3 3
    4 4
    5 5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \foreach \i in {1,...,6} {%
        \pgfplotsset{extra x tick labels={(\symbol{\numexpr96+\i\relax})}}%
        \ifnum\i>1%
            \ifnum\i=4\else%
                \pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/ylabel style={opacity=0}}%
            \fi%
        \fi%
        \ifnum\i<4%
            \pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/xlabel style={opacity=0}}%
        \fi%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.33\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[height=4cm]{sub\i.tikz}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \ifnum\i=3%
            \newline
        \fi%
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]